# Display multiple DT tables in R Viewer

Tags: html, r, dt

I have two DT tables which have the same number of columns/rows. I would like to display them both in R Viewer below each other. I tried using print but it just creates two different views.

I tried using browsable from htmlTools package which I think works fine. However it makes two tables overlap also the scroller on the right overlaps with the table. Just wondering if there is a way setting table margins? I tried adding into style option but it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

t1<-data.frame(matrix(data = round(rnorm(285), 3), nrow=15, ncol=19,
                      dimnames = list(NULL,seq(from=0, to=0.9, by=0.05))), check.names=FALSE)

t2<-data.frame(matrix(data = round(rnorm(285), 3), nrow=15, ncol=19,
                      dimnames = list(NULL,seq(from=0, to=0.9, by=0.05))), check.names=FALSE)

dt_t1 <- datatable(t1,
                      caption = paste0("Variable tested: "),
                      rownames=TRUE,
                     fillContainer = F,
                      options =list(pageLength = 20,
                                    dom = "t", 
                                    ordering = F,
                                    autoWidth = TRUE,
                                    initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                     "function(settings, json) {",
                                    paste0("$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '", "9pt", "'});"),
                                    "}"),
                                    columnDefs = list(list(width = '30px', targets = 0), list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,2)))
                                    )
                                   )


dt_t2 <- datatable(t1,
                   caption = paste0("Variable tested: "),
                   rownames=TRUE,
                   fillContainer = F,
                   options =list(pageLength = 20,
                                 dom = "t", 
                                 ordering = F,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                   "function(settings, json) {",
                                   paste0("$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '", "9pt", "'});"),
                                   "}"),
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '30px', targets = 0), list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,2)))
                   ))



browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$div(
      style = 'display:block; float:top; margin-right:30px;',
      dt_t1
    ),
    tags$div(
      style = 'display:block;float:top; margin-right:30px; margin-top:0px;',
      dt_t2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there is `combineWidgets` in the `manipulateWidget` package:

```
library(manipulateWidget)
library(DT)

combineWidgets(
  datatable(iris[1:5,]),
  datatable(iris[1:5,]),
  ncol = 2, colsize = c(1,1)
)
```

But oddly that doesn't work: this results in a blank window.

However, this works if you encapsulate within `manipulateWidget`:

```
manipulateWidget({
  combineWidgets(title = "The iris data set", 
                 ncol = 2, colsize = c(1,1),
                 datatable(iris),
                 datatable(iris))
}, select = mwSelect(1:3))
```

Comment: Hi Stephanie, this didn't work for me. I am running this in R Studio not Shiny which I think is the reason.  I added some code above which produces both tables in a single view but needs some formatting which I am struggling with.

Comment: @Joana `manipulateWidget` works in the RStudio viewer. I don't know why you're talking about Shiny.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent please note that manipulateWidget actually does use shiny, this is the reason why you get a blank screen and it does work by the encapsulation (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/manipulateWidget/vignettes/manipulateWidgets.html).

Comment: @Joana you might try to use a R-markdown notebook and knit this to HTML. I need to be honest and tel you that I am trying to do the same and use the htmlwidgets i(datatable) n Bookdown and I am still trying to get it formatted the way I want. So please post your solution as soon as you have one (will do the same)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by editing formatting. I added `class="compact"` inside datatable which reduced spaces between columns and and then removed `display:block;` and `float:top;` from browsable which fixed table overlap.

````
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

t1<-data.frame(matrix(data = round(rnorm(285), 3), nrow=15, ncol=19,
                      dimnames = list(NULL,seq(from=0, to=0.9, by=0.05))), check.names=FALSE)

t2<-data.frame(matrix(data = round(rnorm(285), 3), nrow=15, ncol=19,
                      dimnames = list(NULL,seq(from=0, to=0.9, by=0.05))), check.names=FALSE)

dt_t1 <- datatable(t1,
                   caption = paste0("Variable tested: "),
                   rownames=TRUE,
                   width = "95%",
                   height = "95%",
                   class="compact",
                   fillContainer = F,
                   options =list(pageLength = 20,
                                 dom = "t", 
                                 ordering = F,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = 0)),
                                 initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                   "function(settings, json) {",
                                   paste0("$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '", "9pt", "'});"),
                                   "}"))
                   )
)


dt_t2 <- datatable(t1,
                   caption = paste0("Variable tested: "),
                   rownames=TRUE,
                   width = "95%",
                   height = "95%",
                   class="compact",
                   fillContainer = F,
                   options =list(pageLength = 20,
                                 dom = "t", 
                                 ordering = F,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '40px', targets = 0)),
                                 initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                   "function(settings, json) {",
                                   paste0("$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '", "9pt", "'});"),
                                   "}"))
                   )



browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$div(
      dt_t1,
      style = 'width:95%; margin-bottom: 30px;'
    ),
    tags$div(
      dt_t2,
      style = 'width:95%; margin-bottom: 30px;'))))```
````